# add values to one variable with for loop totalSum Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have some values that come randomized to an variable.
Now i want to add every value to each other to get an total sum but the loop wont add them together.

The index variable work when i console log it. but not the total sum of a current value and the index value.
Any tips ?

This is the loop
 // The indexValue is values I get from an array//

```
  var indexValue = index;  // Random number from 1 - 10
    var totalSum = 0;

   for(var x = 0; x <indexValue; x++){

   var currentValue = index[x];
   totalSum += currentValue;
    }

    console.log(totalSum);
```

Comment: I think it should be `var indexValue = index.length;`

Comment: What is `index`? What exactly does it mean if a variable "does not work"?

Comment: on your first line, were u intending to do "var indexValue = index.length" ?

Comment: have tried with index.length.

But no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming since you're referencing `index[x]` that `index` is an array. If so, you are assigning the wrong value to `indexValue`. Try this:

```
var indexValue = index.length;
```

What this does is assign the length of the array to the variable `indexValue`. Now the `for` loop will run from 0 to n where n is the length of the array.

This should get you the values you need.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

Below is a link to a jsFiddle I created with your example and the code explained:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fhU67/)

```
var index = [1,2,3,4,5];  

var indexValue = index.length;  // It's imperative that this is an array
var totalSum = 0;

for(var x = 0; x <indexValue; x++){
    totalSum += index[x];
}

alert(totalSum);
```

The code above is a modified version of what you posted. The current value is not needed and has been removed. In this case, I created an array and stored the values in index. The length is computed, and the values are added together.

For the easy sake of testing, I changed `console.log(totalSum);` to `alert(totalSum);`. It will produce the same value just the same.

Just a reference note on `console.log`. Some browsers (mainly IE) who do not attach the debugger to the process automatically without a page refresh will through an error as `console` will be `undefined`. Here is a quick fix for that:

```
if(window.console && window.console.log) {
    console.log(totalSum);
}
```

This checks that (a) the console object is attached to the global window object and (b) that the log object of console is attached to the console object.

Comment: It still gives me value = 0 ;
but if I console.log the index, it shows me the current value.
but totalSum 0

Comment: @Dymond See the edit above. Are you sure index is an array? You're original comment `// Random number from 1 - 10` leads me to believe that it is not.

Comment: aaa ofcourse. now when you said it. Its actually an string array, that I put values in with an loop . and then i get the value with getElement.. but when there are back. its a singel value, and not an array.  
So what I have to do is save the values in an array, and then call them with your function.. thank you :) now i really need the noob badge here :)

Comment: @Dymond Haha. Nah its all good buddy. I'm glad it's working for you. Good luck and happy coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

you probably want something like this:

```
var sum = 0;
for (var i=0; i < index.length; i++) {
    sum += index[i];
}
console.log(sum);
```